# ListTile error in flutter when passing parameters

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i am trying to pass different parameters in ListTile widget using function, but i don't know how to do it,
here i how i am trying it,

**Passing Parameter from widget;**

```
Widget listSection =Container(
  child: Row(

    children: [
      _listSectionMethod("TITLE 1", "hello i am subtitle two"),
      _listSectionMethod("TITLE 2", "hello i am subtitle two"),

    ],
  ),

);
```

**Method to use those parameters in listtile;**

```
Card _listSectionMethod(String title,String subtitle){
return Card(
  child:ListTile(
  title:Text(title),
  subtitle:Text(subtitle),
  ),
);
}
```

Expected result:
i am trying to show list tile with title and subtitle, on a card.

**Error:** RenderBox was not laid out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fayakon, i think you need to use `Column` (for vertical widgets) instead of `Row` (for horizontal widgets) to get get the desired result,

```
child: Column(
 children: <Widget>[
   _listSectionMethod("TITLE 1", "hello i am subtitle two"),
   _listSectionMethod("TITLE 2", "hello i am subtitle two"),
 ],
)
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Hope this helps. Learn more about Flutter layouts here - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout

Comment: Thank you, i am new, i was confused when to use column in method and when to use column in widget, as they both are same i guess?

Comment: ofc i am following that cookbook from documentation, now i was trying to advance on listtile.

Comment: You're welcome, you can learn more about layouts in the included link above. Please mark it as answer to help others with similar question.